# Why isn't `"repeat" * 3` the same as `3 * "repeat"` in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, methods, operators, associativity

When I type this:

```
puts 'repeat' * 3
```

I get:

```
>> repeat repeat repeat
```

But it's not working if I do this:

```
puts 3 * 'repeat'
```

Why?

Comment: It's a leaky abstraction. http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html

Comment: i'd argue its not a leaky abstraction, there is no reason to assume that * is commutative for string and fixnum.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Ruby, when you call `a * b`, you're actually calling a method called `*` on `a`. Try this, for example:

```
a = 5
=> 5
b = 6
=> 6
a.*(b)
=> 30

c = "hello"
=> "hello"
c.*(a)
=> "hellohellohellohellohello"
```

Thus `<String> * <Fixnum>` works fine, because the `*` method on `String` understands how to handle integers. It responds by concatenating a number of copies of itself together.

But when you do `3 * "repeat"`, it's invoking `*` on `Fixnum` with a `String` argument. That doesn't work, because `Fixnum`'s `*` method expects to see another numeric type.